# Create child association from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have 2 associated models and am trying to create the child from the parent's controller:

```
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :employee
    belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
    
    validates_presence_of :body, :employee_id, :commentable_id, :commentable_type
end
```

In my controller I accept the params for comment:

```
def create
      @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)

      if @purchase[:discount] && @purchase[:discount] > 0
        @purchase[:discount] = @purchase[:discount].round(3)
      end

      if @purchase.save
        render json: @purchase, status: :created
      else
        p "errors", @purchase.errors 
        render json: @purchase.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
  end

private

def purchase_params
  params.require(:purchase).permit(
    :sale_type, :weeks, :weekly_cost, :date, :discount, :client_id, :id, :created_at, :updated_at, :employee_id, :consultation_id, :program_id, :purchaseable_type, :purchaseable_id,
    comments_attributes: [:body, :id, :employee_id, :commentable_type]
  )
end
```

When I attempt to create the purchase with the following params, I get the error:

```
purchase = {
            client_id: client.id,
            weeks: 5,
            weekly_cost: 295,
            comments_attributes: [{
                employee_id: employee.id,
                body: "This is a test",
                commentable_type: "Purchase"
            }]
        }

#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007fb0ef3849e0 @base=#<Purchase id: nil, weeks: 5, weekly_cost: 295.0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, client_id: 18, discount: nil, employee_id: nil, comment: nil, referral_used: false, deleted_at: nil, date: nil, sale_type: nil, purchaseable_type: nil, purchaseable_id: nil, program_id: nil>, @messages={:"comments.commentable_id"=>["can't be blank"]}, @details={:"comments.commentable_id"=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>
```

There's no way to know the `commentable_id` before saving the purchase.  What am I missing?

Comment: Does this help? https://thoughtbot.com/blog/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through

Comment: You should remove `:id` from your list of accepted parameters as it should be generated on the database side.

Comment: @Schwern I tried that with no luck :(

Comment: `commentable_type` cannot be `comment` as in your test. It's a polimorphy of the parent then it should be `Purchase`. Also you can delete `commentable_type` from the authorized params and instead build the child in the controller associated with the view containing the form like `@purchase.comments.new`

Comment: Good call, @Maxence.  That was a typo